# how to calculate difference between dates in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table named Employees with Columns: PersonID, Name, StartDate. I want to calculate 1) difference in days between the newest and oldest employee and 2) the longest period of time (in days) without any new hires. I have tried to use DATEDIFF, however the dates are in a single column and I'm not sure what other method I should use. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  SUM(days_before_next_hire) AS days_between_newest_and_oldest_employee,
  MAX(days_before_next_hire) - 1 AS longest_period_without_new_hire
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATE_DIFF(
      StartDate, 
      LAG(StartDate) OVER(ORDER BY StartDate), 
      DAY
    ) days_before_next_hire
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in the example below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' StartDate UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-03' StartDate UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-13' StartDate 
)
SELECT 
  SUM(days_before_next_hire) AS days_between_newest_and_oldest_employee,
  MAX(days_before_next_hire) - 1 AS longest_period_without_new_hire
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATE_DIFF(
      StartDate, 
      LAG(StartDate) OVER(ORDER BY StartDate), 
      DAY
    ) days_before_next_hire
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
)
```

with result

```sql
Row days_between_newest_and_oldest_employee longest_period_without_new_hire  
1   12                                      9
```

Note use of `-1` in calculating `longest_period_without_new_hire` - it is really up to you to use this adjustment or not depends on your preferences of counting gaps

Answer (score 0):

1) difference in days between the newest and oldest record

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT DATE(created_at) date, *
  FROM `githubarchive.day.201901*` 
  WHERE _table_suffix<'2'
  AND repo.name = 'google/bazel-common'
  AND type='ForkEvent'
)

SELECT DATE_DIFF(MAX(date), MIN(date),  DAY) max_minus_min
FROM table
```

2) the longest period of time (in days) without any new records

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT DATE(created_at) date, *
  FROM `githubarchive.day.201901*` 
  WHERE _table_suffix<'2'
  AND repo.name = 'google/bazel-common'
  AND type='ForkEvent'
)

SELECT MAX(diff) max_diff
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_DIFF(date, LAG(date) OVER(ORDER BY date), DAY) diff
  FROM table
)
```